# Webpack extract SASS SCSS to js or json file

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, sass

For a project i'm currently working on I'm building an Angular application with webpack which will have multiple themes/stylesheets. I'm currently extracting the theme stylesheets into separate CSS files, which is perfect.

However, I have all theme variables in separate SCSS files and I need those variables in my Angular code as well. Now, because of the AOT compilation i cannot import the variable SCSS file.

I'm using the webpack setting below for the specific theme file(s):

```
{
   "include" :["vars.scss"],
   "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
   "loaders": ["sass-variable-loader"]
}
```

When I use the ExtractTextWebpack plugin, I can use the raw-loader to save this to a .txt file (with the variables in a JSON object), but can't save this to JS. Using the raw-loader this still includes the 'modules.export' prefix, so I can't save this as json either...

When I set this vars SCSS file as an entrypoint, the output is not present in my output directory.

Is there any way to:

1. Convert the SCSS variables to JSON or JS?
2. Save this data to either a JSON or JS file in the output directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exporting your variables from SASS to JSON, you can put shared variables into a JSON file and import them both to SASS and JS. You should be able to this in Angular using the [node-sass-json-importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-json-importer) package.

**settings.json**

```
{
    "background-colour": "#FFF",
    "foreground-colour": "#333"
}
```

**main.scss**

```
@import "settings.json"

body {
    color: $foreground-colour;
    background-color: $background-colour;
}
```